# How do I avoid hitting user Quota Limit

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace, google-apps-script, google-apps-for-work

The following Script grabs all my contacts from specific group into a Google Sheet. Ideally I'd like to have it run as often as possible. Currently, with a trigger set to every 1hr, I receive the following quota limit after about 3 hours. After 12 hours of hitting the quota, it resumes for 3 hours and repeats.

> Temporary problem - please try again later and consider using batch operations. The user is over quota.

Aren't quotas on a 24 hr cycle? Is there something wrong with my script?

```
function onOpen()
{
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = [];
  menuEntries.push( {name: "Read Contacts", functionName: "readContacts"} );
  spreadsheet.addMenu("Contacts", menuEntries);
};


function readContacts() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Contacts");

  var group  = ContactsApp.getContactGroup('Apptivo Contacts');
  var contacts = ContactsApp.getContactsByGroup(group);
  var ContactArray  = new Array();
  var ContactArrays = [];

  ContactArray = [];
  ContactArray.push("");
  ContactArray.push("FullName");
  ContactArray.push("Emails");
  ContactArray.push("PhoneNumbers");
  ContactArray.push("Company");
  ContactArray.push("Job Title");
  ContactArray.push("Notes");  
  ContactArray.push("HomeAddress");
  ContactArray.push("WorkAddress");
  ContactArray.push("URL");
  ContactArray.push("Groups");

  ContactArrays.push(ContactArray);

  for (var i=0;i<contacts.length;i++)
  { 
    ContactArray = [];
    ContactArray.push("");

  //FullName
    ContactArray.push(contacts[i].getFullName());

  //Emails
    var Emails = "";
    for ( var g=0;g<contacts[i].getEmails().length;g++)
    {
      Emails += contacts[i].getEmails()[g].getAddress();
      if (g + 1 == contacts[i].getEmails().length) break
      Emails += "\n";
    }
    try{ContactArray.push(Emails);}
      catch(e){ContactArray.push("N/A")}

  //Phone Numbers
    var Phones = "";    
    for ( var g=0;g<contacts[i].getPhones().length;g++)
    {
      if (contacts[i].getPhones()[g].getLabel() == "MOBILE_PHONE") {
        Phones += "C: "
      } else if (contacts[i].getPhones()[g].getLabel() == "WORK_PHONE") {
        Phones += "W: "
      } else if (contacts[i].getPhones()[g].getLabel() == "HOME_PHONE") {
        Phones += "H: "
      } else if (contacts[i].getPhones()[g].getLabel() == "HOME_FAX") {
        Phones += "F: "
      } else if (contacts[i].getPhones()[g].getLabel() == "WORK_FAX") {
        Phones += "F: "
      } else {
        Phones += "O: "
      }
      Phones += contacts[i].getPhones()[g].getPhoneNumber();
      if (g + 1 == contacts[i].getPhones().length) break
      Phones += "\n" ;
    }
    try{ContactArray.push(Phones);}
    catch(e){ContactArray.push("N/A")}

  //Company  
    try{ContactArray.push(contacts[i].getCompanies()[0].getCompanyName());}
    catch(e){ContactArray.push("N/A")}

  //JobTitle
    try{ContactArray.push(contacts[i].getCompanies()[0].getJobTitle());}
    catch(e){ContactArray.push("N/A")}

  //Notes  
    ContactArray.push(contacts[i].getNotes());

  //Addresses
    var homeAddress = "" , workAddress = "";     
    for ( var g=0;g<contacts[i].getAddresses().length;g++)
    {
      if (contacts[i].getAddresses()[g].getLabel() == "HOME_ADDRESS") {
        homeAddress += contacts[i].getAddresses()[g].getAddress();
      } else if (contacts[i].getAddresses()[g].getLabel() == "WORK_ADDRESS") {
        workAddress += contacts[i].getAddresses()[g].getAddress();
      }
    }
    //Home
    try{ContactArray.push(homeAddress);}
      catch(e){ContactArray.push("N/A")}
    //Work
    try{ContactArray.push(workAddress);}
      catch(e){ContactArray.push("N/A")}  

  //URLs  
    try{ContactArray.push(contacts[i].getUrls()[0].getAddress());}
    catch(e){ContactArray.push("N/A")}

  //Groups
    var ListofGroups = "";    
    for ( var g=0;g<contacts[i].getContactGroups().length;g++)
    {
      ListofGroups += contacts[i].getContactGroups()[g].getName();
      ListofGroups += " | ";
    }
    try{ContactArray.push(ListofGroups);}
      catch(e){ContactArray.push("N/A")}


    ContactArrays.push(ContactArray);
  }

  //If Array is not blank(to avoid quota issues)
 if (12 < ContactArrays.length) {
  // Re-populate sheet
   sheet.clear();
   sheet.getRange(1,1,ContactArrays.length,ContactArrays[0].length).setValues(ContactArrays);
   }

};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is room to reduce the number of `get*` calls in your script -- these calls are what drains the Google Services quota. To start with a simple example,

```
for ( var g=0;g<contacts[i].getEmails().length;g++)
{
  Emails += contacts[i].getEmails()[g].getAddress();
  if (g + 1 == contacts[i].getEmails().length) break
  Emails += "\n";
}
```

can be replaced with

```
var contactEmails = contacts[i].getEmails();
for ( var g=0; g<contactEmails.length;g++)
{
  Emails += contactEmails[g].getAddress();
  if (g + 1 == contactEmails.length) break
  Emails += "\n";
}
```

Although this doesn't affect the quotas, I'll mention [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) methods of JavaScript arrays, which could shorten the above to

```
var Emails = contacts[i].getEmails().map(function(email) {
  return email.getAddress();
}).join("\n");
```

Similarly, the repeated calls to `contacts[i].getPhones()` should be replaced with one `var contactPhones = contacts[i].getPhones();`, and subsequent work should happen with this array.

Same for companies, addresses, groups, etc.

Comment: Thanks Zaq! I'll make the adjustments, and give it a try.

Comment: Amazing! this worked perfectly! thanks Zaq. The script runs for a fraction of the time now! from 2 mins to under 20sec. I assume once my quota resets it will no longer hit that limit.. I'll confirm in 24hrs

Comment: Confirmed. Not exceeding quota with a trigger ever 30 min

Answer (score 1):

The [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/101774/how-do-i-avoid-hitting-user-quota-limit/#101777) from [@zaq](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/135384/zaq) is exactly correct. You're basically calling Google APIs each time you perform a `getXXX()` call, so all of those returned payloads should be cached -- only make those calls when you really need a refresh of the values. [Google Apps Script](http://developers.google.com/apps-script) is powerful and it's free (for the most part), so let's all keep it that way by minimizing your calls -- your script will run faster too!

Also useful to the conversation are [the overall Apps Script quotas](http://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas), most on a daily basis while others have a finer granularity. Towards the bottom of that page, you'll also find specific error messages to help with debugging. Here is a [troubleshooting page](http://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting) from the docs with even more tips.

DISCLAIMER: I'm a Developer Advocate for Apps Script. Beginners can learn from several videos I've made to introduce developers to it. Go to [this YT playlist](http://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLOU2XLYxmsILOIxBRPPhgYbuSslr50KVq) and check out episodes 5, 8, 22, and 24. I should have a few more coming later in 2017.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se] It's great to have a developer advocate participating here.